# Injecting a mock into a spied object of the same type

Tags: java, mockito, spy

My object under test implements an interface, and has a field whose type is this same interface (a delegate). I want both a Mock object that I can inject into the `delegate` field of the object under test, and I want the object under test to be a Spy (not really relevant in this example, but in my situation I want to be able to stub some of the object's methods).

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UselessTest {

  @Mock private Useless mock;

  @Spy private UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest() {};

  @Before public void before() { underTest.delegate = mock; }

  @Test public void testDoNothing() throws Exception {
    underTest.doNothing();
    verify(mock).doNothing();
  }

  public interface Useless { void doNothing(); }

  public abstract static class UnderTest implements Useless {
    public Useless delegate;
    @Override public void doNothing() { delegate.doNothing(); }
  }

}
```

I'd like to use the `@InjectMocks` annotation instead of the `@Before` initialization method, but I haven't been successful so far.

I'm using Mockito 1.9.5 and JUnit 4.11.

I have tried several solutions, each one failing for a different reason. :

```
@Spy @InjectMocks private UnderTest underTest;

@Spy @InjectMocks private UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest() {};

@InjectMocks private UnderTest underTest = Mockito.spy(new UnderTest() {});
```

With the first solution, the test ends up in error with the exception `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException` (the abstract class `UnderTest` cannot be instantiated by Mockito)

With the second solution, the test ends up in error with the exception `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException` (Mockito tried to inject the object under test into itself instead of the mock with the same interface)

And finally with the third solution, the test ends up in error with the exception `java.lang.NullPointerException` while calling the test method (Mockito did not inject the mock into the `delegate` field)

Comment: Mockito's IoC is a bit more limited than, say, Spring's.  I've had some cases where I have to use reflection in the @Before to modify a private instance member by hand.